# Automatically replace verbatim environment with lstlisting?

Tags: environments, rmarkdown, quarto

To generate all of my Python code output into LaTeX, I have used Quarto, which formats the output of all Python code blocks in the `verbatim` environment. For example, take the following code in Quarto markdown syntax:

````
```{python}
print(1+1)
```
````

This should transfer to

```
\begin{verbatim}
2
\end{verbatim}
```

But the problem is, I don't want to use the `verbatim` environment! I want Quarto to automatically use the `lstlisting` environment for all its code outputs instead, as `verbatim` does not support automatic line wrapping for long lines of code output. I don't want to find and replace all because I need a long-term solution, and my teacher also needs the .qmd file when submitting so they can replicate the generated .tex file themself.

Is there a way to modify Quarto so that it uses `lstlisting` when formatting code output when I press Render PDF? Or add some magical LaTeX code that replaces all occurrences of the `verbatim` environment with `lstlisting`?